# MVC 4 and jQuery intellisense - is there a better way?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to enable intellisense for jQuery 2 in Visual Studio 2012.
The only way I can find to make it work is to add the

```
@if (false) {<script src="path/to/jquery-2.0.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" />}
```

to EVERY view that I want to use jQuery in.
To put it simply, this is not acceptable.
Is there another way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open - package manager console
write

```
Install-Package jQuery
```

and it will automatically install the files that you need.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.  Under your Scripts folder, there should be a file called _references.js.

Mine looks like this:

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.8.2.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery-ui-1.8.23.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" />
/// <reference path="knockout-2.1.0.debug.js" />
/// <reference path="modernizr-2.5.3.js" />
/// <reference path="ViperAjax.js" />
/// <reference path="RenderSelectList.js" />
/// <reference path="PleaseWait.js" />
```

This adds intellisense for all these files.

Comment: I tried this early on, with no joy... I am curious, do I have to reference the uncompressed dev files? (I was referencing the minified files) - thanks

Comment: Honestly, I don't know...  I've never tried it with the min files.

Comment: I manage jquery using NuGet and it takes care of this for me.